# Number of steps to reduce a number to 0 by reducing "number/2" (integer Division eg. 3/2=1) in each step

Tags: divisibility

I want to know that is it possible to tell directly the number of steps to reaching 0 from a given number given that a number can be reduce to its half in each step. For Example :

9 
step 1:9/2=4 (Integer)

step 2:4/2=2

step 3:2/2=1

step 4:1/2=0

So number of steps 4.

IS there any Direct way for this ????

Comment: Do you know of something called the natural logarithm? If not, read it up. The answer to : how many steps does $n$ take to reach zero, is $\Big\lceil\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}\Big\rceil$, whenever the argument is not an integer, and $\Big\lceil\frac{\ln n}{\ln 2}\Big\rceil$ when  the argument is an integer.

Comment: Thanks. I know Log() but did not know about this property :)

Comment: Please, still check the above formula. It  may have small mistakes, but surely the answer is along these lines.

Comment: Two small corrections to the formula: if $n$ is negative, then you need to take $\ln |n|$. And when $n$ is a power of $2$, You need to add one to the answer. (Example: $\frac{\ln 2 }{ \ln 2} = 1$, but to get from $2$ to $0$ by integer division requires two steps.) So a revised answer is $1 + \Big\lfloor\frac{\ln |n|}{\ln 2}\Big\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to know how many steps you need to reduce a number to $1$ by dividing by $2$ calculate $log_2^a$, where $a$ is your target number. As the answer should be integer take $\lfloor log_2^a \rfloor$ (round down). Finally add one as you want the number to reach $0$ not $1$.